# Linux watch and terminfo

Tags: linux, terminal, perl

I am using `watch` to periodically run a perl script that requires `Term::Size` to obtain the terminal width using

```
$columns = Term::Size::chars *STDOUT{IO}
```

Curiously, `$columns` is an empty string in this case. Does `watch` somehow manipulate `STDOUT` or the terminfo database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `watch` uses pipes to collect output from the subprocess, as you can see from `watch 'ls -l /proc/self/fd'`

```
Every 2.0s: ls -l /proc/self/fd      ...

lrwx------ 1  64 Aug  7 16:28 0 -> /dev/pts/6
l-wx------ 1  64 Aug  7 16:28 1 -> pipe:[42416612]
l-wx------ 1  64 Aug  7 16:28 2 -> pipe:[42416612]
lr-x------ 1  64 Aug  7 16:28 3 -> /proc/3509/fd
```